# Pipeline for : running automated tests in ad hoc fashion against an EXISTING build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I need to be able to select a test or test suite in VSTS and run my automated tests against an existing build. I am finding it difficult to find this process documented in MSDOCS. Has anyone else set this up? I thought I'd create a Release pipeline that just copies the binaries for me, but, that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You likely will find the answers to what you are asking at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops).

If you want to do the testing utilizing the release pipelines picking tests from the Test Plan view (run with options):

- Create the pipeline and add the steps that do the deployment
- Add the Test Task and to select tests using "Test run"

If you want to do the testing utilizing the release pipelines running the same suite every time:

- Create the pipeline and add the steps that do the deployment
- Add the Test Task and select tests using "Test plan".  Select the Suite you want to run

If you've defined the tests in code and want to use something like nUnit to do the discovery, you can run with just assembly name.  You might do this for Unit tests on the build pipeline.  To accomplish this:

- On the pipeline, add the Test task.  Target "Test assemblies".  Then select the filter for identifying the *.dll.

Answer (score -1):

1,You need first to associate your test cases in vsts to your test methods from Visual Stuido. You can find the detailed steps in Microsoft docs: [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops)

2, Then create release pipeline and add test task to run your tests. You can find the detailed steps in Microsoft docs: [Run automated tests from test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

Comment: That's just it, I have already done the things you've suggested.

Comment: Hi @Su Llewellyn How did it go? Can you share some screenshots? Please let me know if there is any question.

Comment: I have already created a release pipeline and added the test task to run my tests.Will add screen shots in a bit.